# steam won't install on chromebook 15.04

Tags: 15.04, steam, chromebook

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my chromebook, the new way through usb boot, and it won't let me install steam, it downloaded the package and took me to the software center for download but all it is saying is "dependency is satisfiable: curl" I'm not really sure what with means and most solutions I've either don't work or are based on drivers and such and I'm pretty new to all of this and need an explanation on how to fix this in a as nooby way as possible.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu using Crouton or Chrubuntu or official version of Ubuntu? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/647232/edit) the question above and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to install curl?

`apt-get install curl`

Then try to rerun the Steam installer.

If that does not work then run `apt-get -f install` which will install any missing dependencies, and then try to rerun the steam installer.